# ASP.Net MVC model as dictionary in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dictionary

I would like to take the model as  in view?

```
   @model Dictionary<string,List<string>>
        <table width="60%">
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                    <td>
                        ___Category___
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ___Detail___
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                         @Model.Key
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Model.Count
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
```

How could I do this?

here is my view with razor syntax.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. Below is the sample

```
@model Dictionary<string,List<string>>

@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in Model)
{
  <label> @pair.Key</label>
  <div>
    @foreach(string data in @pair.Value)
     {
      <span>@data </span>
     }
  </div>

}
```

Comment: I have tried but it is giving me an error that is an opening "<" is missing the corresponding closing ">"

Answer (score 0):

Add `@model Dictionary<string,List<string>>` to your view (assuming Razor is used).

Comment: I have tried but it is giving me an error that is an opening "<" is missing the corresponding closing ">"

Comment: Are you *not* missing a closing `>`? Are you using Razor?

Comment: Which means that you're missing a closing `>` - there should be 2 `>`. You might want to post your view...

Comment: @model Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Comment: Try adding namespaces: `System.Dictionary<System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Dictionary<string, List<string>>

@foreach (var group in Model)
            {
                <h2>@group.Key</h2>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                </tr>

                    @foreach (var aString in group.Value){    
                   <tr>
                            <td>@aString </td>
                   </tr>
                    }

                </table>
            }
```

Comment: I have tried but it is giving me an error that is an opening "<" is missing the corresponding closing ">"

Comment: Is your view exactly like mine above? As that should work as is. If not pls update your question with the full view. It sounds like you have some other razor that is incorrectly formed.