# View model type visible on page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some views that use a dictionary as a model like so:

```
@Model Dictionary
```

When I am looking at them in the browser i see this at the top of the page:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.String] Dictionary
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018239/asp-net-mvc-model-as-dictionary-in-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a full type declaration because you are missing the generic key-value types. The generic Dictionary declaration uses the following format:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The other problem is that the model declaration should be lowercase like `@model`.

So here is an example declaring the model type, and then using the actual Model returned from your controller:

```
@model Dictionary<Guid, string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@foreach (string val in Model.Values)
{
    <p>@val</p>
}
```

Comment: That's not technically true.  The OP could be using the non generic dictionary

Comment: Based on his error he is clearly using a generic Dictionary. The non-generic dictionary is called Hashtable, and i don't see why you think he could be using a Hashtable based on his example.

Comment: You Kind of answered my question(inadvertently) so Ill go ahead and give it to you, but the answer was to use `@model` as you did and not `@Model`